# Brush automatically switch to clay after every click

Tags: sculpt-mode, brushes

I am having an issue in Sculpt mode where my brush is automatically switching (to clay) after every click. I have tried reinstall blender and restart my laptop, but it does not work. I also reset all settings to default and still it doesn't work. I am using Mac and Blender 3.4.1.

Could anyone please help me with this issue, many thanks.

Comment: Restarting would have fixed this issue if it were a keystroke event mishap that made the computer think a key was held down, and reinstalling blender would possibly clear configuration data, but you might want to also load factory defaults. Also, there is the possibility of a bad download, but this doesn’t sound like that.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried reinstalling and even tried an earlier version but still it doesn't work, and neither does restart

Comment: You misunderstand. I was telling you what your attempted fixes would’ve been able to solve, and thus what is not the problem. Did you try loading factory defaults?